# How do you put a string inside a 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a polling program that takes five issues and puts the issue on the row of a 2d Array. Also how would I make the program count how many times a person rated the issue. For example if five people gave rating of five how would I write the program to count the rating and put it on the 2d Array.

These are the instructions:

Write a simple polling program that:

- Allows users to rate five social-consciousness issues from 1 (least important) to 10 (most important);
- Pick five causes that are important to you (e.g., political issues, global environmental issues). Use a one-
  dimensional array topics (of type String) to store the five causes;
  To summarize the survey responses, use a 5-row, 10-column two-dimensional array responses (of type int):
- Each row corresponding to an element in the topics array.
  When the program runs, it should ask the user to rate each issue. People in the range of (5, 13) have respond to the survey. Then have the program display a summary of the results, including:

a) A tabular report with the five topics down the left side and the 10 ratings across the top, listing in each column the number of ratings received for each topic.

b) To the right of each row, show the average of the ratings for that issue.

c) Which issue received the highest point total? Display both the issue and the point total. d) Which issue received the lowest point total? Display both the issue and the point total.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
public class Polling {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static String[] issues=new String[20];
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
   issues[0]="Global Warming";
   issues[1]="Earth Quakes";
   issues[2]="Stopping war";
   issues [3]="Equal Rights";
   issues[4]="Curing Cancer";
   int[][] polling =new int[5][10];
   Random rand=new Random();
   int random=rand.nextInt(9)+5;
   int poll=0;

   String polling2=Arrays.toString(polling);


   for(int i=1;i<random;i++){
       System.out.println("Person"+i);
       System.out.println("Rate these issues from 1-10");

       System.out.println(issues[0]);
       int zero=console.nextInt();
       System.out.println(issues[1]);
       int one=console.nextInt();
       System.out.println(issues[2]);
       int two=console.nextInt();
       System.out.println(issues[3]);
       int three=console.nextInt();
       System.out.println(issues[4]);
       int four=console.nextInt();


}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: You can not put a `String` inside an `int` array. Just use an internal logic to assume that index 0 of your `polling` array represents ratings for issues[0], index 2 of your `polling` array represents ratings for issues[1] and so on. At the time of summarizing you can display actual String content for index 0..4 by referring to `issues` array. Is this a homework?

Comment: Yea and i'm having hard time figuring this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
public static final String[] ISSUES = {
    "Global Warming",
    "Earth Quakes",
    "Stopping war",
    "Equal Rights",
    "Curing Cancer",};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int pollings = rand.nextInt(9) + 5;
    int [][] rates= new int[pollings][ISSUES.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pollings; i++) {
        System.out.println("Person" + i);
        System.out.println("Rate these issues from 1-10");
        for (int j = 0; j < ISSUES.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(ISSUES[j]);
            rates[i][j] = console.nextInt();
        }
    }


     // ADDED
    int minRating = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxRating = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minRatingIndex = -1;
    int maxRatingIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ISSUES.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(ISSUES[i]+":");
        int rating = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < pollings; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t"+rates[j][i]);
            rating += rates[j][i];
        }
        double average = ((double)rating)/pollings;
        System.out.println("\tavr: "+average);
        if (rating < minRating ){
            minRating = rating;
            minRatingIndex = i;
        }
        if (rating > maxRating ){
            maxRating = rating;
            maxRatingIndex = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max points:\t"+ISSUES[maxRatingIndex]+":\t"+maxRating+" points");
    System.out.println("Min points:\t"+ISSUES[minRatingIndex]+":\t"+minRating+" points");

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: It is not the same, with my solution, you can calculate whatever you want .

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm running into errors on this code

Comment: It had bad initialicing, try with:
int minRating = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxRating = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

Comment: I think the problem is with maxperson

Comment: Thanks soon much. I been working on this problem literally all day and without you I wouldn't have finished it.

Comment: If it isn't too much to ask could you please explain the last part of the code which deals with rating>maxRating and rating<minRating